# Length of schema changes after flatMap and when printed multiple time in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, schema, jupyter-notebook

**Update:**
Over a year had passed, I still have not figured this out. But I found that even just do a `cout()` could mess up the length of the schema. Here is the code:

```
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print blaParsed.count()
    print "multiple print: "
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
```

Here is the output:

```
    73
    1435
    multiple print: 
    5905
    5905
    73
    73
    73
    73
```

Again, 73 is the correct length, after the `count()`, it changes to 5905. After *several* `print`s, it goes back to  correct 73. And the '*several*' changes for each run.

**Original Question:**

Would anyone please help me with this PySpark issue? I've spent days on this. Just cannot figure out why the length of my schema changes when I printed it out multiple times. The version of Spark is 2.2 and I am using Jupyter Notebook to run the code on a cluster of 20 nodes.

Here is my code:

```
    import myReader

    # read data from binary files
    data=sc.binaryFiles('Data/20171006')

    # binary file reader convert binary file to a tuple of schema and data array
    # the 1st item in the tuple is the schema of type StructType
    # the 2nd item in the tuple is a numpy 2D array
    tableWithSchemaRDD = data.map(myReader.convert)

    # print out the length of the schema to check its length
    # since the schema is the same for all items in the RDD, I only check the first one
    print "1st print: ", len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])

    # extract the data array from RDD
    tableRDD = tableWithSchemaRDD.map(lambda x:x[1])

    # print out the length of the schema to check its length again
    print "2nd print: ", len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])

    # flatmap so each item in the rdd is a row instead of 2D array
    # and sort all the rows by the last item in each row, which is a timestamp 
    rowRDD = tableRDD.flatMap(lambda y:[z for z in y]).sortBy(lambda x:x[-1])

    # print out the length of the schema multiple times
    print "multiple print: "
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
    print len(tableWithSchemaRDD.first()[0])
```

Here is the output:

```
    1st print: 73
    2nd print: 73
    multiple print: 
    3961
    3961
    3961
    3961
    73
    73
```

As you can see that the first 2 `print` printed out the correct length of the RDD, 73, but after the `flatMap` transformation, it increased to a much larger number. Then after a while, i.e. 4 `print` statement, it returned to the correct length. Sometimes, the wrong number is not 3961, but any other number of multiple of 72, then plus 1. I guess that is because the first 72 StructField of my schema is the name of the data, the 73rd StructField is a time stamp, so the number 3961 is 72 * 51 + 1. I also saw number 11737, 23401, 9793, 2017, etc.

Another thing I'd like to mention is that if I put the code in `myReader` in the same notebook instead of import it as a module. I do not see this problem. I used `sc.addPyFile()` to distribute my module to the nodes.

Any comments and suggestion would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As this question is stated right now, there is nothing unexpected about the result. Since you sort:

```
.sortBy(lambda x: x[-1])
```

Spark has to shuffle data and, in case of ties, can choose an arbitrary element as the `first` one. As a result value can change from run to run.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. May I ask why you think there would be ties? All the timestamps are unique, which are used to `sortBy`.